# Instance of an object as function using function operator

Tags: c++, c++11

An instance of an object as a function using function operator

How can the following code work, particularly declaring an instance then using it as a function call? line 2. 
How should the function operator be done?

```
Temp<int> inst(3);
inst(1, 1) = 3;
Temp<int> & instref = m;
std::cout << instref(1, 1);
```

Comment: `operator()(int, int)`

Comment: I think you're looking for the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator).

Comment: Override `operator()` as `int& operator()(int, int)`